# Output of seaborn's lmplot does not plot a scatterplot and linear regression

Tags: python, seaborn, linear-regression, data-science

first time asking something here on stackoverflow.

I have encountered a problem while using seaborn's lmplot.

my dataset after cleaning it up is simple like this: [image of data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Frvmh.png)

I am trying to create a facetgrid scatter plot that has a linear regression (which is what lmplot is used for), using:

- stationame for col (dtype object)
- year for x axis (dtype integer)
- monthtotal for the y axis (dtype integer)

to look something like this: [lmplot example from seaborn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPlfI.png)

Below is my code and I was expecting a scatterplot + regression that looks like the above example.

```
ridership_year = ridership_mg.groupby(['stationame', 'year']).monthtotal.sum().reset_index()
sns.lmplot(x = 'year', y = 'monthtotal', col ='stationame', data= ridership_year, col_wrap = 5)
```

However, the figure output was this:
[seaborn lmplot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNgnC.png)

What can I do to remedy this situation? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: did you mean to use a `regplot` instead?

Comment: hey ernest, definitely not.

I'm looking to make a facetgrid using the different station names as the col, and having a linear regression for all of them. 

Something which lmplot is supposed to be used.

Comment: In this case you probably want to spend more words on what's wrong with the output, because not knowing your data at all, it's rather hard to see the problem.

Comment: hey thanks for the input. I've edited the post with more information

Comment: Seems the only problem is the scale of the x axis? So if you zoom in it should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

There is a parameter in lmplot called truncate which restricts the graph boundary to the data. Thanks for the help!

> truncate : bool, optional
>
> By default, the regression line is drawn to fill the x axis limits
>   after the scatterplot is drawn. If truncate is True, it will instead
>   by bounded by the data limits.

```
sns.lmplot(x = 'year', y = 'monthtotal', col = 'stationame',
          data = ridership_year, truncate = True,
          col_wrap = 5)
```